# Question about criterion for the existence of holomorphic logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

**Theorem 6.2** of Stein's *Complex Analysis* says that: if $f$ is a nowhere vanishing holomorphic function on a **simply connected region** $\Omega$, then f has a holomorphic logarithm on $\Omega$.

A question here on stackexchange also states the same theorem:
[Existence of logarithm of holomorphic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2494993/existence-of-logarithm-of-holomorphic-function)

However, if I directly use the **principle branch** of logarithm (That is, for $z=re^{i\theta}$ we define the logarithm $log(z)=log(r)+i\theta$, with |$\theta|<\pi$) to define a function $g$ so that $g(z)=log(f(z))$ provided that **the image of $f$ on $\Omega$ is contained in** $\mathbb{C} \backslash (-\infty,0]$, then we would have $g'(z)=\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ by chain rule and we know that $g$ is holomorphic. It seems that $\Omega$ need not be simply connected or even connected.

Perhaps in the process above some step is wrong but I didn't find any. Could anyone help?

Comment: What makes you think  that the principal branch of logarithm is a analytic on $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy My bad. Then what if the image of $f$ is contained in $\mathbb{C} \backslash (-\infty,0]$? I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comment that got too long:

Note that $\mathbb{C} \backslash (-\infty,0]$ is a simply connected set avoiding zero so $\log w$ is defined and analytic there, hence one can do a composition $\log \circ f$ which is analytic; same proof applies if the image of $f$ is contained in a simply connected set $U$ not containing zero.

However, such a condition on the image of $f$ is very restrictive as for example it means that the image of $f$ cannot contain any full circle (or for that matter any Jordan curve) that encircles the origin

The result quoted in the original post is much more general as one needs only that the domain of definition of $f$ is simply connected but the image can be any (open) set that avoids zero (eg full punctured plane) and $f$ can be very complicated. As we saw in the beginning applying this theorem to $g(w)=w$ and the domain  $\mathbb{C} \backslash (-\infty,0]$ or any other simply connected open $0 \notin U$ containing the image of $f$ immediately gives us by composition that $\log f$ exists in those cases

Comment: I see. So both is correct but the theorem on the book holds on more general conditions. Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes you are right - happy to be of help